# Cross site session with NodeJS/Passport/Express backend w/Polymer in front

Tags: node.js, express, polymer, passport.js

I've got a node/express/passport backend listening on port 3001 which I'm hitting directly with the browser to authenticate. It authenticates and controls access to protected urls just fine. The front-end is polymer and served on a different port(8080) for dev. After authentication express redirects the browser to the polymer app. The problem is when the polymer app then makes an iron-ajax call back to the express backend, the auth cookie/session handle doesn't get passed, so the backend denies the request.

In production I'm thinking the backend will be on a different sub-domain (backend.foo.com) from the frontend (users.foo.com).  Curious if anyone knows how to get express/passport to set a session cookie that will be shared across all the sub domains?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cross-site sessions and subdomain cookies are quite different things.

To make your sessions cookies available for subdomains, you should be able to do something like this:

```
app.use(express.session({ 
  cookie: {
    path: '/',
    domain: '.example.com',
  }
}));
```

To have the sessions available across different, unrelated domains, you would have to use a more complicated mechanism to share data between domains but even though the title of your question suggests that you need the latter, the content of your question asks about the former so a subdomain cookie is all you need.

Also read about CORS - Cross-origin resource sharing - and make sure that nothing is blocked due to misconfigured CORS because that can be sometimes a real pain to configure correctly for situations like this.

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing

Comment: I did this on the production site, but I have the same problem. After the backend.bar.com redirects to foo.bar.com, the browser gets the cookie with a domain of .bar.com. Then when foo.bar.com makes an iron-ajax call to backend.bar.com, it doesn't pass the cookie.

Comment: @RichardRowell That can be related to CORS. See my updated answer.

Comment: Thanks again, once I added res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true"); to my middleware and narrowed the Access-Control-Allow-Origin it started working.